# How to have multiple instances of a jQuery effect

Tags: jquery, instance, fade

First, the disclaimer- I'm JUST starting out with jQuery. I apologize for my ineptness. :)

My issue is that I'm attempting to use a jQuery rollover effect on a bunch of separate elements on a page. Right now, when I mouse over one, they all do the effect at once because they have the same class name, and jQuery is selecting all of them. I know I could use a different name for each, and write a separate bit of jQuery for each class, but is there a better way? I plan on having many of these elements.

Anyway, a picture is worth a thousand words. Check out the source of my test page here: [Click Here](http://www.kthornbloom.com/test) Mouse over the 'test' images. I want the effect to just apply to the one you mouse over.

Here's my novice jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$('.box').hover(function() {
 $('.rollover').fadeIn('slow');
 $('.description').fadeIn('fast');
});

$('.box').mouseleave(function() {
 $('.rollover').fadeOut('slow');
 $('.description').fadeOut('fast');
});


});
```

Comment: Good question, I've been giving everything seperate ID's up until this point.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
   $(this).next('.rollover').fadeIn('slow');
   $(this).find('.description').fadeIn('fast');
}, function() {
   $(this).next('.rollover').fadeOut('slow');
   $(this).find('.description').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

The `.hover()` method accepts *two* functions to fire for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Within each function, the `this` keyword refers to the `.box` element that received the event. Then you use `.find()` to get the nested `.description`, and `.next()` to get the adjacent sibling `.rollover`.

- http://api.jquery.com/hover/
- http://api.jquery.com/find/
- http://api.jquery.com/next/

In your situation, you could use `.siblings('.rollover')` instead of `.next()` if you want.

- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: +1, but it would be nice to add an explanation, as it's such a good illustration of what `this` does.

Comment: @chryss - Yes, I had already updated my answer with an explanation of what `this` represents. Was that what you meant?

Comment: Careful with the `this` keyword; it doesn't always resolve how you would think.

Comment: @palswim - In this sort of situation, it is perfectly safe to rely on `this` to represent the DOM element that received the event.

Comment: yes: it wasn't visible to me at that point in time on SO. I'm sure some updates are shown first to the author before they ripple down into the main database, if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

If I could select them one at a time, I think I could apply the effect only to their children. I just wish you could tell jquery to just select whatever your mouse is over without stating an ID or Class...